# Getting the following exception when trying to render a large PDF in Oracle EWPS

Tags: oracle, websphere-8

While trying to process a large PDF file I get the following stack trace.  This is only happening when we try a large PDF and does not impact the majority of work.  This is Oracle Enterprise Web Processing Services (EWPS) Axis2 running on WebSphere Application Server version 8.5.5.13.  We think it is an issue with a timeout setting but are not sure what setting to modify.

```
[5/10/19 3:38:50:458 CDT] 000000b1 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause AxisServlet: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error writing stream: OutputStream encountered error during write
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:417)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printUserWSDL(AxisService.java:936)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printWSDL(AxisService.java:1056)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent.processListService(ListingAgent.java:280)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:229)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1114)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:949)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: Error writing stream: OutputStream encountered error during write: com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.ClosedConnectionException: OutputStream encountered error during write
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferOutputStream.write(WCCByteBufferOutputStream.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTOutputStream.write(SRTOutputStream.java:97)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.writeOut(BufferedServletOutputStream.java:590)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.flushBytes(BufferedServletOutputStream.java:433)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.flush(BufferedServletOutputStream.java:405)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:310)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:154)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:288)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.writeWSDL(WSDLWriterImpl.java:84)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printDefinitionObject(AxisService.java:920)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printUserWSDL(AxisService.java:934)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printWSDL(AxisService.java:1056)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent.processListService(ListingAgent.java:280)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:229)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1114)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:949)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 104  Connection reset by peer
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.<init>(AsyncLibrary.java:924)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.get(AsyncLibrary.java:937)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary.getIOException(AsyncLibrary.java:951)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncChannel.multiIO(AbstractAsyncChannel.java:482)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncSocketChannelHelper.write(AsyncSocketChannelHelper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncSocketChannelHelper.write(AsyncSocketChannelHelper.java:396)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioSocketIOChannel.writeAIO(AioSocketIOChannel.java:282)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioTCPWriteRequestContextImpl.processAsyncWriteRequest(AioTCPWriteRequestContextImpl.java:54)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.TCPWriteRequestContextImpl.writeInternal(TCPWriteRequestContextImpl.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.TCPWriteRequestContextImpl.write(TCPWriteRequestContextImpl.java:353)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.asynchWrite(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:2518)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.sendOutgoing(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:2302)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundServiceContextImpl.sendResponseBody(HttpInboundServiceContextImpl.java:901)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.writeBufferAsynch(WCChannelLink.java:517)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.writeBufferResponse(WCChannelLink.java:494)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.writeBuffer(WCChannelLink.java:438)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferOutputStream.flushWriteBuffer(WCCByteBufferOutputStream.java:719)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferOutputStream.write(WCCByteBufferOutputStream.java:225)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTOutputStream.write(SRTOutputStream.java:97)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.writeOut(BufferedServletOutputStream.java:590)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.flushBytes(BufferedServletOutputStream.java:433)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.flush(BufferedServletOutputStream.java:405)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:310)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:154)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:288)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.flush(PrintWriter.java:331)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.extensions.AbstractSerializer.endMarshall(AbstractSerializer.java:47)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.extensions.soap.SOAPOperationSerializer.marshall(SOAPOperationSerializer.java:47)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.extensions.ParseUtils.writeExtensibilityElements(ParseUtils.java:128)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.writeBindingOperation(WSDLWriterImpl.java:340)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.writeBinding(WSDLWriterImpl.java:323)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.writeDefinition(WSDLWriterImpl.java:197)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.writeWSDL(WSDLWriterImpl.java:93)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.writeWSDL(WSDLWriterImpl.java:83)
    ... 30 more

    at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.writeWSDL(WSDLWriterImpl.java:86)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printDefinitionObject(AxisService.java:920)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printUserWSDL(AxisService.java:934)
    ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Means the other side most likely (as in very very most likely) closed the connection during the file transfer/data IO.

Comment: What do I need to modify then to prevent this from happening?